# How to change value of pre-defined variable in GitLab to all lowercase

Tags: gitlab, variables

My environment requires the use of the predefined variable `CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE` in `.gitlab-ci.yml`; however, this variable is in all caps, which makes my build job fail. I've tried several ways to convert the value of this variable to all lowercase with no success:

```yml
variables:
  CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE: $CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' # doesn't work

build_image:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: #...
    entrypoint: #...
  before_script:
    - export CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE=$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' # also doesn't work
```

I have successfully hard-coded this variable for my own use, but I need the script to work for other users as well without requiring them to hard-code it themselves. Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Comment: You're on the right track with your before_script, but there are some quoting issues. It helps to test out these commands in a local shell first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had it almost right. You just can't pipe variable itself to tr. You have to use echo in command substitution, which you can pipe to tr.

```
before_script:
- export CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE=$(echo "$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
```